# Cannot hide clock in 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, time, tweak

I've just upgraded my 16.04 LTS where time was not shown. But 18.04 LTS seems to force me to see a clock on the desktop. Tweaks options does not work either:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To completely hide the clock from top panel you can use [Clock override](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/) GNOME extension, which lets you have a custom clock format. Then in the extension settings leave the text field in front of `Text to display instead of the clock` empty. Refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/810348) for how to install GNOME extension.

[image: Source: extensions.gnome.org] Source: extensions.gnome.org

Comment: Ok, even for empty string it shows bullet, but that's fine with me. Thanks.

Comment: @prasimix you mean that dot next to the clock? It's the notifications indicator, as soon as you clear your unread notifications it should disappear

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution to this issue. First of all, you need to install gnome shell in order to get a gnome shell extention which is capable of hiding date&time indicator. Then install this app https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/ After installation go to extension settings and tap on 'misc'. Uncheck 'date menu' and that's it.[Here how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX7Z6.png)

Note: this extention works on Ubuntu 18.04 however, since it's no longer supported it doesn't work on 18.10.

By the way this is my first answer on askubuntu.com
I hope it was helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Hide Clock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1110/hide-clock/) from *GNOME shell extensions*. It automatically hides the clock shown in the *Top Bar* with no needs for config.